# Oracle JDBC 10 Driver + UCP for JDK 17 and Oracle 19c Possible for Project?

Tags: java, oracle, java-17, ojdbc, ucp

I just started developing a POC for an app on Java 17. We utilize Oracle and specifically have integrated our other app with Oracle UCP.

The compatibility matrix on [Oracle's website](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) (under the 19c section) shows the UCP package is only certified with jdk8 / jdk11. For ojdbc10 it **is** certified with jdk17; however, it's my understanding that the ucp + ojdbcXX needs to a companion. My question is: Following the Oracle matrix it doesn't look like 19c + jdk17 + UCP is a possibilty, can i get confirmation that i'm reading that correctly? Additionally, is there a way to link the 2 together outside of having the ojdbc+ucp match 1:1 with versions.

I tried utilizing UCP + ojdbc10 and ran into the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "UCP-CriticalTaskExecutorThread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/ons/Subscriber
    at oracle.ucp.common.ONSDriver.createSubscriber(ONSDriver.java:121)
    at oracle.ucp.common.FailoverDriver$1$1.run(FailoverDriver.java:226)
    at oracle.ucp.common.FailoverDriver$1$1.run(FailoverDriver.java:222)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at oracle.ucp.common.FailoverDriver$1.run(FailoverDriver.java:221)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPTaskBase.call(UCPTaskBase.java:20)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPTaskManagerImpl$3.run(UCPTaskManagerImpl.java:202)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.ons.Subscriber
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add ons.jar and simplefan.jar in the class path? or you can set the property oracle.jdbc.fanEnabled to FALSE and try it out. Please check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/JDBC-support-Oracle-FAN.html#GUID-069265AF-BBEE-4682-9906-98D8429BFC1C) for more details on the property.